# Properties of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

So I was trying to prove some properties or rather lemma related to Fourier Transform. I got stuck at this point:
I have a function function $$f \enspace \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R} )$$  and its Fourier transform is given by $$\hat{f} $$ The real and imaginary part of the function are indicated respectively by $$Re(f)\enspace and \enspace Im(f)$$
So now I need to prove that : $$If \enspace f\enspace  is\enspace  real, \enspace then\enspace  Re(\hat{f})\enspace  is \enspace even\enspace  and\enspace  the \enspace Im(\hat{f})\enspace  is\enspace  odd.$$
How can I prove it? Any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform of $f$ follows the relation

$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}\xi\;e^{2\pi i \xi x}\hat{f}(\xi)
$$

Taking the complex conjugate in both sides

\begin{eqnarray}
f^*(x) &=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}\xi\;e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\hat{f}^*(\xi) \stackrel{k=-\xi}{=} -\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}{\rm d}k\;e^{2\pi ik x}\hat{f}^*(-k) \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}k\;e^{2\pi ik x}\hat{f}^*(-k) \\
&\stackrel{f\;{\rm is\; real}}{=}& f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}k\;e^{2\pi ik x}\hat{f}(k)
\end{eqnarray}

This is true only if

$$
\hat{f}^*(-k) = \hat{f}(k)
$$

Or equivalently

\begin{eqnarray}
\Re\{\hat{f}(-k)\} -i \Im\{\hat{f}(-k)\} &=& \Re\{\hat{f}(k)\} +i \Im\{\hat{f}(k)\} \\
\Re\{\hat{f}(-k)\} &=& \Re\{\hat{f}(k)\} \quad\mbox{Real part is even}\\
-\Im\{\hat{f}(-k)\} &=& \Im\{\hat{f}(k)\} \quad\mbox{Imaginary part is odd}
\end{eqnarray}